# Holomorphic function on unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{ z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$.

Does there exist a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ with $f(3/4)=3/4$ and $f'(2/3)=3/4?$

Schwartz's lemma is not working. I am not having any idea how to solve this types of problem. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(z) = \frac{3}{4} z + \frac{3}{16}$

Clearly $|f(z)| \leq  \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{16} = \frac{15}{16} < 1$ and $f$ has the rquired property, namely

$f(\frac{3}{4}) = \frac{3}{4}$ and $f'(\frac{2}{3}) = \frac{3}{4}$

Comment: how you construct this example...please give me the right way to solve this problem so that  can solve other problems of this types... types

Comment: @ Neela I just tried with an affine map and it just worked. What kind of problem are u solving?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1521065/analytic-function-on-an-open-disc Please help me to solve this problem...this is the same problem..

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem its my old problem with no answer...

Comment: @ Neela Usually to solve this type of question one need to apply Schwartz Lemma. otherwise try with map like $az+b$.  Another thing I just want to know Is it NET question?

Comment: yes its Csir Net question...

Comment: if az+b does not gives exactly then what to do?

Comment: in 4th option z-1 is working...

Comment: in 3rd option Schwartz will work...am i right?

Comment: in 4th $z-1$ doesn't map unit disk to itself. But 3rd yes schwarz lemma works

Comment: Then how to solve 4th option....please help me how to solve 4th option...as i will complete the whole question..remaining part are solved by your help...

Comment: and one more thing i like to know that Schwartz lemma does not gives existence of this types of map...how to say that if certain map satisfies the condition of schwartz then that map wil exist .

Comment: @Neela  I already posted a solution. Check and let me know. In general  one can use Nevanlinna Pick interpolation or  Caratheodory- Fejer  interpolation result. See wiki for detail.